# If using function that can return null  

Tags: java, oop, function, if-statement

There is a function get() that return a value if it is there in ArrayDeque otherwise returns **null** i.e x can be some value or null. If get() returns x then function B() should perform some computations otherwise should not do anything.

```
T get()
{
    //compute x
    return x;
}

void B()
{
     int z;
     if(y.get()!=null)
     {
          z=y.get(); // gives null pointer exception
          .....
     }
}
```

The problem is that y.get() already returns the value which is not assigned to any variable, thus gives null pointer exception. If i use something like `if((z=y.get()) != 0)` it gives exception in cases when x is null. How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: How can you return null and assign it to the int variable z ?? Its type mismatch.

Comment: Neither of the versions you write should throw, unless it's `get` itself that throws. Are you sure you're looking at the right part of your code?

Comment: Thats why i put that check in if condition.

Comment: So, does `get()` return `T`, or an `Integer`?  B() seems to assume that it's an Integer.

Comment: y.get() will throw a null pointer only if y is null...or may be some logic inside your get() is throwing an exception...

Comment: @all i am using arraydeque function peekfirst inside get()

Comment: @ShashankKadne: You're forgetting there's an assignment to an `int`, which is going to involve unboxing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is an `ArrayDeque<Integer>`, right?

When you have:

```
int z = y.get();
```

That's like saying:

```
int z = ((Integer) y.get()).intValue();
```

Just use:

```
Integer z = y.get();
```

instead. Then you can test whether `z` is null. On the other hand, if `y.get()` has already returned a non-null value, I'm surprised if it's *then* returning a `null` value - you'd expect it to return the same thing twice, right? Are there other threads involved?

Additionally, it's not clear what you mean by this:

> The problem is that `y.get()` already returns the value which is not assigned to any variable, thus gives null pointer exception.

I don't see where the "thus" in here... it's fine to call a method and not store the return value in a variable. If that's throwing a `NullPointerException`, it would really suggest that `y` is null. Of course, all of this would be easier to diagnose if you would post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

As an aside, it's not clear why you're calling `y.get()` twice in the first place. I would restructure the code to:

```
void B()
{
     Integer z = y.get();
     if (z != null)
     {
         // Use z
     }
}
```

Do you *really* want to call it twice?